# Nothing Inserting into Table within LOOP after fetching values successfully from CURSOR

Tags: oracle, plsql

So I have a cursor (C4) that is being fetched into a variable (o_var) and I am fetching the variable correctly (the values for **HR** and **calc_id** are printing to my console); however, nothing is being inserted into my CALC table. Am I missing something here? Been trying to debug this for hours now...

Thanks in advance

```
Open C4;
LOOP
    FETCH c4 into o_var;
    EXIT WHEN c4%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line('v_calc_id: ' || v_calc_id || ', hr: ' || o_var.hr);
    insert into calc (calc_id, calc_Date, calc_name, report_dt, create_dt)
    values(null, sysdate, 'TEST', o_var.hr, sysdate);
END LOOP
Close C4;
```

Comment: Does your calc_id allow null?

Comment: @TonyDong, yes. I have a trigger / sequence set up to autopopulate this value. One thing to note is when I do a regular insert (without running my procedure) , it works perfectly using the same values

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to commit! Changes won't be applied to the database until then.